# Thread safety when different processes access same resources

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, singleton, httpclient

I am working with windows services to get some data from an API

service#1 gets data from "http://api.provider.com/Entity1"

service#2 gets data from "http://api.provider.com/Entity2"

and I have both these services in one .csproj and I use a singleton httpClient to retrieve data from API:

```
public sealed class Client : HttpClient{

private static readonly object padlock = new object();
private static Client instance = null;
public static Client Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new Client();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}

private Client()
{
    DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
    DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("...", "...");
}

public async Task<string> Get(string url)
{
    var result = await GetStringAsync(url);
    return result;
}}
```

but these processes are parallel so the singleton class is a shared static class between the two.And Then I have this class as the consumer fo the first:

```
class APIHAndler{

public List<obj1> f1()
{
    var jsonResult = Client.Instance.Get(url1).Result;
    //make list of obj1 out of json
}

public List<obj2> f2()
{
    var jsonResult = Client.Instance.Get(url2).Result;
    //make list of obj2 out of json
}

}
```

What I did is to create one instance of the class `APIHAndler` in each of my services and call f1 and f2 based on the ongoing business and I get this error:

***Response status code does not indicate success: 429 (Too Many Requests).***

I think it is probably due to the fact of having two different connections open at the same time. but I don't know how to avoid this. If you can help me fix this or have a better solution I will be very happy to hear about.

Comment: Do you call web service in loop? Maybe you call endpoints too frequently?

Comment: No, but I actually call it in two different windows services which are running at the same time to access two different resources from the API

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to avoid this

The service you're calling should have documentation that explains what causes a 429. Sometimes it's only a single request at a time; more often it's a certain number of requests within a time window. Either way, you'll need to throttle your requests, and you can build throttling with a `SemaphoreSlim`.